# SQL loop vs IN(...) clause

Tags: sql, loops, in-clause

I have a dynamic SQL statement that will process potentially millions of rows on each call.  The incoming parameter lists can be null, but if populated, they can contain 1 or more parameters.  The mid-tier framework I'm working with is generic enough that any Stored proc on the DB server can be called via the same webservice method call and I don't have the option of making any alteration in the mid-tier.  So, the incoming parameter list of VARCHARS originally looked like:

```
        IF (@acct_nums is not null)
            SET @SQL_Y2 = @SQL_Y2 + ' AND a.acct in ('+ @acct_nums +') '
        IF (@source_codes is not null)
             SET @SQL_Y2 = @SQL_Y2 + ' AND a.source in ('+ @source_codes +') '
```

The above means that if the UI wants to pass a list of acct nums in, it will need to pass the formatted list as

```
    '''123456'' '','' ''456789'''
```

However, the suggestion has been made to avoid this formatting by the UI and create the dynamic query like:

```
        IF (@acct_gl_nums is not null)
            SET @SQL_Y2 = @SQL_Y2 + ' AND a.acct_gl in ('''+ @acct_gl_nums +''') '
        IF (@source_codes is not null)
             SET @SQL_Y2 = @SQL_Y2 + ' AND a.source in ('''+ @source_codes +''') '
```

However, this I think will only support 1 value in each parameter (otherwise I don't think i can format the VARCHAR list to look like --> ('123456','4546789') <--).  To address this, the suggestion is to break the incoming list up and loop round the values, executing the statement once per value.

I'm no SQL expert, but won't this be hideously expensive?  I've 2 potential parameter lists with no upper limit on the number of values in each, and even if I did, isn't executing the statement multiple times via a loop going to be more expensive than executing it once with the IN statement populated with all values?

As mentioned before, I can't alter the design therefore can't amend the incoming parameters so a Mid Tier fix to address this issue isn't feasible.

Comment: You might want to specify your application language/UI and db.  For instance, recent versions of SQL Server have an `Array` parameter type that some libraries can use.  You also need to validate the list somehow, or you risk SQL Injection.  One of the best all-around options is to split the list into some sort of temp-table you can just join to - there are questions for specific dbs floating around.

Comment: Hi - UI is C#, MT is java, sybase 15.5

Comment: Create a temp table and insert the incoming list values into them? Like that!